# Reorganizing data from row with multiple paired data sets R

Tags: r

I am trying to reorganize data where my rows contain a unique ID and the multiple times and volumes. The times and volumes are paired. Endpoint is plotting how volume increases over time for each ID.

Reprex:

```
ID <- c(1:5)
Volume1 <- c("100", "200", "300", "400", "500")
Volume2 <- c("1000", "2000", "3000", "4000", "5000")
Time1 <- c ("10", "20", "30", "40", "50")
Time2 <- c ("20", "30", "40", "50", "60")
df <- data.frame(ID, Volume1, Volume2, Time1, Time2)
```

I think I need to end up with something like

```
|ID  |  Volume  | Time   |
|:--:|:--------:|:------:|
| 1  |100       |  10    |
| 1  |1000      |  20    |
| 2  |200       |  20    |
| 2  |2000      |  30    |
| 3  |300       |  30    |
| 3  |3000      |  40    |
| 4  |400       |  40    |
| 4  |4000      |  50    |
| 5  |500       |  50    |
| 5  |6000      |  60    |
```

Best I could find was possibly use separate_rows from tidyverse, but I can't work it out..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and specify the `names_pattern` to match and capture the non-digits (`\\D+`)

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -ID, names_to = ".value", names_pattern = '^(\\D+)')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#      ID Volume Time 
#   <int> <chr>  <chr>
# 1     1 100    10   
# 2     1 1000   20   
# 3     2 200    20   
# 4     2 2000   30   
# 5     3 300    30   
# 6     3 3000   40   
# 7     4 400    40   
# 8     4 4000   50   
# 9     5 500    50   
#10     5 5000   60
```

---

Or another option is using `names_sep`

```
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
       names_sep = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)") %>%
     select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#      ID Volume Time 
#   <int> <chr>  <chr>
# 1     1 100    10   
# 2     1 1000   20   
# 3     2 200    20   
# 4     2 2000   30   
# 5     3 300    30   
# 6     3 3000   40   
# 7     4 400    40   
# 8     4 4000   50   
# 9     5 500    50   
#10     5 5000   60
```

Comment: When I try this method I get the error: 
New names:
* .value -> .value...2
* .value -> .value...3
Error: `spec` must have `.name` and `.value` columns

Comment: @Troels I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#[1] ‘1.1.3’`  This is based on your example data  only

Comment: @Troels Can you show your `packageVersion('tidyr')` in case you want to debug the issue

Comment: Using Library(tidyr) gave me the 1.0.0 version, but after I install.packages("tidyr") I got the right package. It works as intended in the reprex. I am trying to apply it to my original data right now.

Comment: I accepted both answers, didn't know I was only allowed one. Yours is more elegant so I accepted yours now. Didn't mean to be inpolite.

Comment: You can accept any solutions and is fine with me.  But, I was just confused when you followwed up with this solution and then said that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(ID,Volume=Volume1,Time=Time1),data.frame(ID,Volume=Volume2,Time=Time2))
df[order(df$ID),]
ID Volume Time
1    100   10
1   1000   20
2    200   20
2   2000   30
3    300   30
3   3000   40
4    400   40
4   4000   50
5    500   50
5   5000   60
```

This code just makes a data frame for each group, merges them with `rbind`, and then orders them by ID to get the desired output

Comment: Thank you, that also works. Just quite the typing work when there is 28 columns!